# How to update a JButton in a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I am trying to enable/disable a JButton depending on the current time. The application is bigger, and i have a medication set having a set of medications. If the current time is in one of medication's intake intervals then i want to enable a button. The button just refuses to enable. This is my code:

```
public class MainPanel implements Runnable {
private Thread thread;
public MainPanel(){
        ....ui code
        contentPanel.add(yourMedicationPlansLabel);
        ... 
        root.setLayout(null);
        root.add(contentPanel);
        root.setSize(200, 200);
thread = new Thread(this);
thread.start();
}
@Override
    public void run() {
        if(medicationPlanSet != null){
            updateMedicationPlans(medicationPlanSet);
        }
        while(thread.isAlive()) {
            DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMMM yyyy, EEEE, HH:mm:ss");
            LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
            time.setText("Today is " + dtf.format(now) + ".");
            try {
                thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            root.getRootPane().updateUI();
        }
    }
```

and this is the update method:

```
public void updateMedicationPlans(Set<MedicationPlan> medicationPlanSet)

        for (MedicationPlan medicationPlan : medicationPlanSet) {
            for (Medication medication : medicationPlan.getMedicationSet()) {

                JLabel medicationLabel = new JLabel(medication.getName() + " " + medication.getDosage() + " mg");
                medicationLabel.setBounds(10, y, 200, 30);
                medicationLabel.setForeground(Color.decode("#3e0103"));

                button = new JButton("Taken");
                button.setBounds(320, y, 80, 30);
                button.setForeground(Color.decode("#3e0103"));
                button.setEnabled(false);

                JPanel checksPanel = new JPanel();
                checksPanel.setLayout(null);
                checksPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
                checksPanel.setBounds(210, y + 5, 100, 20);

                int x = 0;
                boolean inTime = false;
                String[] intakeIntervals = medicationPlan.getIntakeInterval().split(",");
                for(String intakeInterval : intakeIntervals) {
                    String from = intakeInterval.split("-")[0].concat(":00");
                    String to = intakeInterval.split("-")[1].concat(":00");

                    if(checkTime(from, to)){
                        inTime = true;
                    }

                    System.out.println(inTime);

                    JLabel canBeTakenLabel = new JLabel();
                    canBeTakenLabel.setBounds(x, 0, 20, 20);
                    canBeTakenLabel.setIcon(canBeTakenImage);
                    checksPanel.add(canBeTakenLabel);
                    x += 25;
                }

                if(inTime) {
                    button.setEnabled(true);
                    root.repaint();
                }
                contentPanel.add(button);
                contentPanel.add(medicationLabel);
                contentPanel.add(checksPanel);
                y += 30;
            }
        }
    }
```

Also tried to put the update method in while(isAlive), and root.updateUI() but nothing works.

Comment: When it comes to threads, Swing programs must adhere to specific rules.  In your case, you should just use [javax.swing.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html) instead of making your own thread;  then you won’t have to worry about those rules at all.

Comment: 1) Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. 2) Don't continually invoke repaint() in your loop. The frame should be updated once after all changes have been made. 3) Don't invoke updateUI(). You are not doing a LAF change. All you need to do is invoke revalidate() and repaint() AFTER all the components have been added to the frame. 4) Don't use the Color.decode() method inside the loop. Color object can be shared, so create one instance outside the loop to save on resources.

Comment: You never use your own thread to update swing ui components. Seriously: don't assume how a framework might work. Read its documentation, and follow a good tutorial.

Comment: also tried with a timer.. all i wanted was depending on the current time a button to be enabled/disabled

Comment: *"also tried with a timer.."* Tip: Add @VGR (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. **BTW:** For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: **_"also tried with a timer"_** was it Swing timer ?